# Saudi Arabia Exit Re-entry from different countries

Tags: visas, saudi-arabia

I have an exit re-entry visa for Saudi Arabia. I exited Saudi Arabia to India this month. I have plans to visit Canada from India. Is it possible to directly travel to Saudi Arabia from Canada using my exit re-entry visa without coming back to India? Is there a condition that exit and re-entry should be to/from the same country?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, there is no such condition.

Visas occasionally specify allowed points of *entry*, but I've never heard of a visa for any country specifying a point of *departure*.

Comment: Thanks, that is the advice I got from other sources as well. I'll take the trip in a couple of weeks and update here.

Comment: @RaghuKaippully Glad to help.  Please accept the answer if it works for you, and do report back on how it went!